# Can method overloading be used without knowing the type at compile time?

Tags: java, polymorphism

If we take a very basic example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    animalMineralOrVegetable(new Animal());
    animalMineralOrVegetable(new Mineral());
    animalMineralOrVegetable(new Vegetable());
}

public static void animalMineralOrVegetable(Animal animal) {
    print("Animal");
}

public static void animalMineralOrVegetable(Mineral mineral) {
    print("Mineral");
}

public static void animalMineralOrVegetable(Vegetable vegetable) {
    print("Vegetable");
}
```

As all the types are known at compile time, we get the expected result.

However, if we rely on a method from another class that, for example, has an `Object` return type, is using `instanceof` and casting our only option (other than reflection)?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    animalMineralOrVegetable(SomeClass.getSubject()); // object return type
}
```

The above obviously wouldn't compile if the declared return type doesn't match one of the method implementations (as above).

Obviously, if the method just returns an interface that each type implements, we'd refactor to a single `animalMineralOrVegetable()` method and call the common print method instead.

I'm trying to avoid repeating code, but constrained by a poorly written legacy API.

Comment: I suppose you now that the usual go-to here is to use virtual methods on the actual implementations?

Comment: Check out reflection, it may be able to solve your issue: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/

Comment: @JornVernee Yes, that is the refactoring approach I was referring to in my question.

Comment: I can't see how reflection would be an elegant solution. I can think of one solution, but I'm not sure it's applicable. I'll write it in an answer, but I'm not sure if it'll help considering the very simple solution you have

Comment: I agree with @ChristopherSchneider that it would not be elegant to use reflection.  It's more of a hack to accomplish what you're asking.  You can use the Object.getClass() to get the string to feed into Class.forName(classNameVariable);

Comment: I would go for reflection tbh. You basically want to do a dynamic method lookup, which you could implement yourself, but reflection is transparent to the JIT compiler and would probably be eliminated for most call sites.

Comment: I may not fully understand the question, then. I'm not seeing why reflection is necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

You've provided a very basic example, but I'd probably try to do something like this:

```
public AnimalOrMineralWrapper{
    String message;
    T t;

    public AnimalOrMineralWrapper(T t, String message){
        this.t = t;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }
}
```

You can now use wrap the classes in this, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Mineral mineral = new Mineral();
    AnimalOrMineralWrapper<Mineral> mineral = new AnimalOrMineralWrapper(mineral, "mineral");
}

public static void animalMineralOrVegetable(AnimalOrMineralWrapper wrapper) {
    print(wrapper.getMessage());
}
```

If print is an API call that you can't just pass anything to, you could add an additional instance variable, or maybe just set `message` to null on object instantiation. Then, just don't make the service call if `message` is null.

This is one potential solution, but I'm going to guess your implementation is more complicated.

Comment: Where this doesn't work for my case is that the printed message isn't constrained by the type - my example is artificial, but in reality, the print method would have to execute something only available on the type.

Comment: Thought that may be the case. The other answer might be your best option. I've dealt with similar issues where someone thought it was a good idea to have everything extend an empty abstract class. We had no choice but to use `instanceof` all over our code to accomodate the API. It's a mess, but there isn't much we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little bit of trouble fully grasping the question. Would it be problematic to pass the object type as a parameter into the `animalMineralOrVegetable()` method?

Presumably you have some sort of abstract parent class that `Animal()`, `Mineral()`, and `Vegetable()` all extend, we'll call it `Food()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Animal animal = new Food();
    Mineral mineral = new Food();
    Vegetable vegetable = new Food();

    animalMineralOrVegetable(animal, Animal.class);
    animalMineralOrVegetable(mineral , Mineral.class);
    animalMineralOrVegetable(vegetable , Vegetable.class);
}

public static void animalMineralOrVegetable(Food foodObject, Class clazz)
{
    if(clazz == Mineral.class)
    {
        // logic
    {
    else if(clazz == Animal.class)
    {
        // logic
    }
    else if(clazz == Vegetable.class)
    {
        // logic
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Class not recognized.");
    }
}
```

EDIT: To deal with an unknown type, how about `instanceof` (as you mentioned in your question). This seems to be pretty straightforward in my opinion. It's easy to follow when you come back to the code months later.

```
public static void animalMineralOrVegetable(Object foodObject)
{
    if(foodObject instanceof Mineral.class)
    {
        print((Mineral) foodObject.getSubject());
    {
    else if(foodObject instanceof Animal.class)
    {
        print((Animal) foodObject.getSubject());
    }
    else if(foodObject instanceof Vegetable.class)
    {
        print((Vegetable) foodObject.getSubject());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Passed object type cannot be determined.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nearly this - the type.class is an interesting approach - but the scenario I was trying to ask is when we start with a `Object` return type, of an instance of an as-yet-unknown type.

Comment: @Mikaveli see my edit. basically, I would use `instanceof`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like another example where [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) would be useful. I assume that all your classes have some common supertype or at least you can easily add one. So code might look something like this:

```java
interface Visitor
{
    void visitAnimal(Animal animal);

    void visitMineral(Mineral mineral);

    void visitVegetable(Vegetable vegetable);
}

abstract class BaseObject
{
    public abstract void visit(Visitor visitor);
}

class Animal extends BaseObject
{
    public String getUniqueAnimalString()
    {
        return "Animal";
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visitAnimal(this);
    }
}

class Mineral extends BaseObject
{
    public String getUniqueMineralString()
    {
        return "Mineral";
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visitMineral(this);
    }
}

class Vegetable extends BaseObject
{
    public String getUniqueVegetableString()
    {
        return "Vegetable";
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visitVegetable(this);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<BaseObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    objects.add(new Animal());
    objects.add(new Vegetable());
    objects.add(new Mineral());

    Visitor visitor = new Visitor()
    {
        @Override
        public void visitAnimal(Animal animal)
        {
            System.out.println(animal.getUniqueAnimalString());
        }

        @Override
        public void visitMineral(Mineral mineral)
        {
            System.out.println(mineral.getUniqueMineralString());
        }

        @Override
        public void visitVegetable(Vegetable vegetable)
        {
            System.out.println(vegetable.getUniqueVegetableString());
        }
    };

    for (BaseObject o : objects)
    {
        o.visit(visitor);
    }

}
```

which produces output

> Animal
>
> Vegetable
>
> Mineral